# Get Data Change Values in Java Server Application from Java Client Application

Tags: java

I want to read opc Tags in JAVA client program and then want to send only data change values for the Tags ( Only the Tags whose Values are getting changed )  to a JAVA Server Application over TCP / IP Network . How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create a subscription from your Client on the Tags you want to get new value.

The Server then will be able to send you each time the new value for the tags that have been updated.

Comment: How can you even come up with an answer to such a poor question?

Comment: The first phrase was good enough for me as a question. I just guessed that he already had set up a OPC Java Server/Client...